# Sitecore user profile Custom Properties not persistant

Tags: sitecore-client

We have recently migrated from `Sitecore 9.3 to Sitecore 10.2`. We are facing a very unusual issue. We are having a functionality where the user is getting authenticated using SSO and a virtual user is created in Sitecore. While creating virtual users we are setting 5 custom properties to that virtual user. Post authentication when the user is redirected to the main page, the custom properties of the user profile are not maintained and get removed. We are using "`return Redirect()`" from that authentication action to the page from which the user initiated login i.e. RelayState.

[image]

[image]

Thank You In Advance,

Lalit Joshi

Comment: You are saying that this worked as expected prior to the migration? In my experience, whenever you are making use of custom properties on Contacts, there is a migration process that needs to take place; especially if the customizations were not implemented with best practices in mind.

Comment: @MarcelGruber - Thank you for your response. We haven't done customization in this case. We are simply using "virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(VirtualUserPropertie.Username, username)" to set the custom property during login and "profile.GetCustomProperty(VirtualUserPropertie.ContactId);" to retrieve the value. Let me know incase you got any details.

Comment: Can you share some of the code where you set and get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Debugging the code on local we found that post authentication custom properties of virtual user profile gets removed automatically. We raised a ticket and got an answer from Sitecore Support that it is a known issue and have provided us with a link to hotfix.

Please use the following URL to download the platform pre-release that contains fixes for them:
https://sitecore.service-now.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001439

Please refer to the documentation to get more details on how to deploy the pre-release to your solution:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-xp-pre-releases.html